# Faster way to find min and max values in array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I was wondering, which way would be faster for the compiler.
Using the sort or a looping method to display min value and max value.
Which is a faster method for the compiler or programmer?

I included the looping method as a comment.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Day3 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Maximum and minimum value array");
        System.out.println("--------------------------------\n");

        //variable declaration
        int amount;
        int[] integerArray;

        //set amount
        System.out.print("Enter the amount of numbers to sort: ");
        amount = scan.nextInt();
        integerArray = new int[amount];

        //input loop
        System.out.print("Enter numbers: ");
        for(int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
        {
            integerArray[i] = scan.nextInt();
        }

        System.out.print("\nHere is your array: " + Arrays.toString(integerArray) + "\n");

        Arrays.sort(integerArray);
        System.out.println("Min value = " + integerArray[0]);
        System.out.println("Max value = " + integerArray[integerArray.length - 1]);
        System.out.println("Median value = " + integerArray[(integerArray.length -1) / 2]);

        /*
        int[] arr = new int[10];
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int i, min=0, max=0;
        for(i=0; i<=arr.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.print("Enter any number: ");
            arr[i] = in.nextInt();          
        }
        min = arr[0];
        for(i=0; i<=9; i++)
        {
            if(arr[i] > max)
            {
                max = arr[i];
            }
            if(arr[i] < min)
            {
                min = arr[i];
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Maximum is: " + max);
        System.out.println("Minimum is: " + min);
        */

    }
}
```

Comment: *"faster for the compiler."*? *"or programmer"*? The only speed performance you should worry about is the runtime performance. I have yet to see code that needs *faster* compiling and faster for the programmer is unclear and 100% person-related.

Comment: Actually, that is wrong.  There are lots of cases where "faster for the programmer" is important ... if you mean faster for the programmer to write and debug!

Comment: @StephenC well, it is true in almost every entreprise context. I have a planning with stict dead-line. If I can't reduce the time to program some functionalities, I am ****. And same thing about debugging (which is funny as it is almost always related to the quick dev done before ;) )

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For **unosorted** data, looping over the array to find min/max takes O(n) time. For **sorted** it would have been constant time (O(1)) but as I understand it, this is not your case.

Fastest sorting algorithms work in O(n*log(n)), so linear scan (loop) is the fastest option there is.

Also, this is not the case when compiler could optimize something for you.

Comment: if the data is sorted finding min and max would be constant time , just access the first or the last element

Answer (score 3):

In general fastest sort you can have will be O(nlogn), looping over the array will be just O(n) so definitely looping

Answer (score 3):

Arrays.sort() uses a version of the mergesort algorithm, which runs in O(nlog(n)). Finding the max and min values through a linear search of the array requires only one pass through the array, making it O(n).

In general, the linear search looping method will run faster. You could also combine the max/min finding with the data input to improve efficiency:

```
   int[] arr = new int[10];
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int i, min=Integer.MAX_VALUE, max=Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for(i=0; i<=arr.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.print("Enter any number: ");
        arr[i] = in.nextInt();   
        if (arr[i]>max) { max = arr[i]; }
        if (arr[i]<min) { min = arr[i]; } 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **JAVA 8 Stream API**. Stream must be faster I think as it doesn't store elements. Stream directly processes the required elements.

Code Sample:

```
List<Integer> integerList = Arrays.asList(1,2,13,4,15,6,17,8,19);
System.out.println("List of Ints= " +integerList);
IntSummaryStatistics intStats = integerList.stream().mapToInt((x) ->x).summaryStatistics();
System.out.println("Max Number= " + intStats.getMax());
System.out.println("Min Number= " + intStats.getMin());
```

I have tested the code & works fine.

Comment: It wouldn't  be faster than a loop.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to other answers

```
public class FindMaxAndMinFromArray {
static void findMaxAndMin(int[] arrNum) {
    Arrays.sort(arrNum);//will sort original array
    System.out.println("Min number is : " + arrNum[0]);//After sorting 0 index will be min value
    System.out.println("Max Number is : " + arrNum[arrNum.length - 1]); //last index will be max value
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int myArr[] = { 75,10, 20,80,65, 30, 40, 50 };
    findMaxAndMin(myArr);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterating a list/array to identify the minimum and maximum entries can be done in a single pass.

And unless your data is already sorted, sorting will always require more effort than a single read over all entries.

So, at *runtime* sorting to just find min and max translates to a certain amount of overhead.

And of course: your terminology is messed up. The compiler translates input to output, it doesn't care about the efficiency of the code you provide as input.